# Python csv get original raw data line

Tags: python, csv, reader

In python it is easy to read and parse a csv file and process line-by-line:

```
reader = csv.reader(open("my_csv_file.csv"))
for row in reader:
    # row is an array or dict 
    parsed_data = my_data_parser(row)
```

where *my_data_parser* is my own piece of logic that takes input data, parses and does logic.

If my parser fails, I would like to log the entire **original** line of csv file, but it seems that from the csv reader i have no more access to it.

Is it possible to retrieve the original raw line data?

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't seem like the [`csv.reader()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) exposes the file object it's iterating, however, you could use the [reader's `line_num`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvreader.line_num) attribute to achieve what you want.

For example:

```python
import csv

file = open("my_csv_file.csv")

lines = file.readlines()

reader = csv.reader(lines)

for row in reader:
    # row is an array or dict
    try:
        parsed_data = my_data_parser(row)
    except MyDataParserError:
        print(f"ERROR in line number {reader.line_num}")
        print("Full line:")
        print(lines[reader.line_num])

file.close()
```

## Alternative

If you'd like to avoid always loading the file into memory, you could instead keep your initial way of reading the file and only read the whole file into memory if an error occurred:

```python
import csv

reader = csv.reader(open("my_csv_file.csv"))
for row in reader:
    # row is an array or dict 
    try:
        parsed_data = my_data_parser(row)
    except MyDataParserError:
        # Only read the whole file into memory when an error occurred.
        file = open("my_csv_file.csv")
        lines = file.readlines()
        file.close()

        print(f"ERROR in line number {reader.line_num}")
        print("Full line:")
        print(lines[reader.line_num])
```

Comment: The downside is you aren't using CSV module anymore. So row is plain text which you need to parse to split on comma, handle optional quotes already handled by CSV. Plus this approach of handling text file one line at a time will mean that any multiline cells will be handled badly. A CSV file of 100 rows might be 250 lines as text file for example. Because of quoted newline chars.

Comment: I missed a part of the solution - I've updated the answer now

Comment: Nice solution! The only downside is that file.readlines() reads the whole file at once and for large files it could be not always desirable.

Comment: Also realised that - Added another solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the row line number with

```
reader.line_num
```

But there seems to be no direct way to access the actual line (says [doc](http://%5Bhttps://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)). Here is iterative method that avoids reading the whole file to memory at any step:

```
import csv 
class MyException(Exception):
    pass

def super_logic(line): # Some silly logic to get test code running
   if len(line) != 2 or line[1] != '1':
       raise MyException("Invalid value")
   print("Process: %s" % line)

class LastLineReader:
    
    def __init__(self, fn ):
        self.fid = open(fn)
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def __next__(self):
        line = self.fid.readline() # Read single line and cache it local object
        if len(line) == 0:
            raise StopIteration()
        self.current_line = line.strip()
        return line
           

reader_with_lines = LastLineReader( "my_csv_file.csv" )
reader = csv.reader( reader_with_lines )
for line in reader:
   try:
     super_logic(line)
   except MyException as e:
     print("Got exception: %s at line '%s'" % ( e, reader_with_lines.current_line ))
```

(Edited: removed other solutions as they are also visible on other ppl posts)

Comment: Agreed. If you think the problem is your processing then just print row object. If you think the raw CSV line is badly formatted in the text file, only then you need to care about row number.

Answer (score 1):

As alternative to reader.line_num

```py
for index, row in enumerate(reader):
    print(i + 1, row)
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution doesn't read the whole file into memory.

It calls csv reader on every read line of the file. Not sure about performance:

```
import csv
f = open(filename, 'r')

# first line are the column names
column_names = next(csv.reader([next(f)]))
for line in f:
    cols = next(csv.reader([line]))
    row = dict(zip(column_names, cols))
```

- line is the original line
- row corresponds to what DictReader would output